Ffmpeg image parameter for YouTube
Is there any image png command equivalent to parameter below?
ffmpeg -loop 1 -framerate 2 -i input.png -i audio.m4a -c:v libx264 -preset medium -tune stillimage -crf 18 -c:a copy -shortest -pix_fmt yuv420p output.mkv
I’m using this command to create png image
ffmpeg -lavfi "color=black:1920x1080, drawtext=text='Example' :fontsize=h/8 :fontcolor=white :x=(w-tw)/2 :y=(h-th)/2" -frames 1 -crf 18 out.png
Is there a way to create png image with command above to make equivalent to match this command below? It’s for YouTube.
ffmpeg -loop 1 -framerate 2 -i input.png -i audio.m4a -c:v libx264 -preset medium -tune stillimage -crf 18 -c:a copy -shortest -pix_fmt yuv420p output.mkv

Your first command includes parameters to control the quality of a video output. The second command outputs a PNG image. As already answered in your previous question, PNG is a lossless format, and therefore requires no parameters to control the quality. Therefore there is no equivalent code....To be able to help, you need to explain exactly what you are trying to do. Currently, I think you are making the wrong assumptions about what you might require

Ok. Thank You for answering my question.

Are you trying to make a still image display for the length of the audio track?

The following command will produce a video output that can be uploaded to youtube. Because it is -crf 0 it is effectively lossless, and would match the quality output of a lossless PNG.
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color=black:1920x1080:d=5 -vf "drawtext=text='Example':x=(w-tw)/2:y=(h-th)/2:fontsize=h/8:fontcolor=white" -crf 0 output.mp4
This will display for 5 seconds (d=5). This can be changed to suit
EDIT
The following code will enable the addition of audio to a generated drawtext background video. Set duration d=5 to match audio duration, and audio extension to suit.
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color=black:4096x2160:d=5 -i audio.aac -filter_complex [0]drawtext=text='Text':fontsize=h/8:fontcolor=white:fontfile=arial.ttf:x=(w-tw)/2:y=(h-th)/2[TEXT] -map [TEXT] -map 1:a -c:a copy -c:v libx264 -preset medium -tune stillimage -crf 18 -c:a copy -pix_fmt yuv420p output.mkv

Thank You So Much.

I tried this ffmpeg -lavfi "color=black:4096x2160, drawtext=text='Text' :fontsize=h/8 :fontcolor=white :fontfile=Arial.ttf :x=(w-tw)/2 :y=(h-th)/2" "output32.png" -i "Audio File" -c:v libx264 -preset medium -tune stillimage -crf 18 -c:a copy -shortest -pix_fmt yuv420p output.mkv it exports with Good quality but with error is there a way to improve the command?

im sorry but the command you gave me is not working.

A typo. There should have been a space before -crf 0. My appologies. Have edited and corrected.

Also, what OS are you using?.

im currently using Windows 10

I have to add -lavfi or otherwise it won’t work

I've edited my answer to add a working command.

Thank You Sark!
